# rewriting results in view: trim from the back

Tags: 7, views

I am working on Drupal 7 Omega Subtheme, Panels Views.
In one of my views I have a path field which displays the whole url and I need only the last 6 characters (6 digits, to be precise. Also, if it helps - part of the URL I want to get rid of is fixed.)
Under REWRITE options there is 'Trim this field to a maximum length' but I need to trim it from the end (i.e. from the right).
Do I have to use php? Do I require views_php module?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will have to use something like

```
$newstring = substr($dynamicstring, -6);
```

in the php code for the field.

Comment: Thanks Gokul. How would I use tokens (namely - [path]) in combination with that?

Comment: Could I do something like  $Dynamicstring == [path]; $newstring = substr($dynamicstring, -6); print $newstring;

Comment: If you are using view_php it should be available to you as a php variable. If you want to use tokens you can use <?php token_replace('[path]'); ?>

Comment: Also, is there a drupal way of doing this as sorting a view using PHP always has a considerable perfomance impact?